# Unable to return zip folder from ASP.NET Core Web API getting 500 internal server. But code is running smoothly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-500

This is my API from Azure function:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(GetPackage))]
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: "get-package", tags: new[] { "asap" }, Summary = "Get Package")]
[OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(UpdateSDRequestInputModel), Required = true, Description = "Get Package")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPackage(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET", Route = "v1/getPackage/{alias}/{jobId}")] HttpRequest req, 
    [FromUri] string alias, [FromUri] string jobId, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext executionContext)
{
    return await ExecuteAndFormResponseAsync(req, executionContext.FunctionName, async () =>
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(await _qPPService.GetPackage(alias, jobId,req));
    });
}
```

This is my `GetPackage` method:

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetPackage(string alias, string jobId)
{
    try
    {
        string _authToken = await GetAuthToken();`your text`

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authToken);

        var addtnlRequest = await _additionalRequestRepository.GetAdditionalRequestAsync($"Additional-{jobId}", alias)
            ?? throw new NotFoundException($"Request with Id: Additional-{jobId} for alias: {alias} does not exists");

        var request = await _requestRepository.GetRequestAsync($"Primary-{jobId}", alias) ??
            throw new NotFoundException($"Request with Id: Additional-{jobId} for alias: {alias} does not exists");

        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri(_qPPEndPoint + "jobs/" + addtnlRequest.QPPRequestId + "/downloads/files?path=" + "3c35af-FullPackage-2308171550.zip")
            };

        var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
        responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        Stream stream = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStream();

         responseMessage.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");

         return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/zip")
                {
                    FileDownloadName = "3c35af-FullPackage-2308171550.zip"
                };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionHelper.LogAndThrowException($"Failed getting package for {jobId} {Environment.NewLine} {ex}", _logAndTelemetryHelper);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Yes bro. But am unable to download zip folder.  not gettting any erros

Comment: As soon as run api that has to return zip folder. thats my requirement Tanveer Badar

Comment: What is the method `ExecuteAndFormResponseAsync`?

Comment: Hi Georgy Tarasov
This api written from azure function. ExecuteAndFormResponseAsync this helps to return content from azure function api

Comment: Please add listing of this function too. I assume that something wrong happens there because this function has name `FormResponse` (maybe it hardcodes multipart/form-data somewhere), but when you return zip files, your content type must be application/zip

Comment: Also why you are trying to add header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` to already executed message?

Comment: I think I found what's wrong. Just remove `new OkObjectResult` wrapper from your main function. Check out my gist. It works ok https://gist.github.com/tarasverq/1974dc9689b9d7aa16e5ba122f4918d9

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove FileStreamResult wrapped in OkObjectResult approach.

So your main method should looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPackage(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET", Route = "v1/getPackage/{alias}/{jobId}")] HttpRequest req, 
    [FromUri] string alias, [FromUri] string jobId, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext executionContext)
{
    return await ExecuteAndFormResponseAsync(req, executionContext.FunctionName, async () =>
    {
        return await _qPPService.GetPackage(alias, jobId,req);
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure let me check and update

Comment: No guys still didnt work. Its same issue. Not able to return zip folder

Comment: Hi Georgy
Apart from OkObjectResult removing approach. I tried removing  ExecuteAndFormResponseAsync as well. Then it worked. Thanks for the reply brother. :)